# Food with a bite that's referring to texture?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, adjectives, nouns

My mother refers to a "bite" as in something to bite on, say [raw carrot bits in a stew](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10206018025640772&set=a.10202073269024322.1073741830.1564999382&type=3&theater&notif_t=photo_comment).

[Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bite#british-1-2-5) only refers to the food sense noun as a strong taste, though:

> bite *noun* (STRONG TASTE) › [U] If ​food has bite, it has a ​sharp
> ​ or strong ​taste: *I like ​mustard with bite*.

That still applies if it were pickles in a tuna salad, but can "bite" also refer to food texture alone? I think it might be more versatile than "crunch" or "chewy".

What is the best word to describe under-cooked carrot bits in a stew, as well as pickle bits in a tuna salad?

Comment: Maybe *firm* or *crunchy*?

Comment: [Homeguides SFGate](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/tree-chestnuts-same-family-water-chestnuts-67735.html) has: '... water chestnuts keep their crunchiness even when well cooked.' [An article on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=124715780964263&id=161982000537012) has: 'If water chestnuts keep their crunch after cooking, does this mean that ...'.

Comment: Are you talking about *al dente* or just plain raw?

Comment: Al dente, but that doesn't fit the pickles, which I'd call *chewy*.

Comment: I call that texture- crunchy, chewy, crispy, are all textures.  Pickle bits add an interesting texture to tuna salad. I have heard people use “bite” but it strikes me as colloquial. “Mouth feel” is also a term but is usually used for liquids and smooth and creamy textures like ice cream.

Comment: "Texture" is too generic. I had tuna with pickle today and the tuna was chewy while the pickle was crunchy, so I probably confused those two while thinking of smooth, non-chunky salad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For carrots in particular you'd describe them as "crunchy". Food with "bite" can either be firm to the tooth or, as you note, strong or pungent in flavour.

Comment: Do you have a source for the firm sense?

Comment: @CeesTimmerman Source added in an answer.

Answer (score 4):

I've been familiar with this meaning as long as I can remember and was quite surprised to find it in the OED only.

> **Bite** (n.)
>
> Chiefly *Cookery*. The quality of having a firm texture or of being
> resistant to biting or chewing.
>
> **1898** A li'l ill-fortune he wants now, same as a salad o' green stuff wants some **bite** to it.
> E. Phillpotts, *Children of Mist* iv. xii.
> 484
>
> **1999** The rice should be tender and creamy, but retain some **bite**.
> *BBC Vegetarian Good Food* April 36/3
>
> **2012** Homemade Thai fishcakes, on a bed of still-warm stir-fried
> vegetables with **bite**, mild chilli-flavoured sambal condiment, and
> cooling chive crème fraiche.
> *Journal*  (Newcastle) (Nexis) 29 June a27
> [OED]

---

In his answer, Mike C mentioned another sense that is also applicable to food, but different from texture:

> **Bite** (n.)
>
> A sharp penetrating effect
>
> *The soup has a peppery **bite**.*
> *The **bite** of the wind on our cheeks* [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bite)

---

This could conceivably lead to ambiguity when describing, for example, a spicy pasta dish without specifying either the pasta or the sauce. *The penne all’arrabbiata (or penne arrabbiata) needed more **bite*** could mean that the pasta was cooked too long  (texture) or that the sauce need more chili pepper (heat).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [**al dente**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al_dente) covers this, as it

> describes pasta and vegetables, rice or beans that are cooked to be firm to the bite.

Comment: But the pickles aren't cooked, are they?

Comment: Pickles may use processed cucumbers (hot water bath for a few minutes).